# Failed to upload packages to PyPI: 410 Gone

Tags: python, pypi

After [pypi.python.org has been migrated to pypi.org](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-June/030766.html), I got an error when trying to upload a package to PyPI using the command as usual:

`python2.7 setup.py sdist upload`

The error message is:

`Upload failed (410): Gone (This API has been deprecated and removed from legacy PyPI in favor of using the APIs available in the new PyPI.org implementation of PyPI (located at https://pypi.org/). For more information about migrating your use of this API to PyPI.org, please see https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading. For more information about the sunsetting of this API, please see https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-June/030766.html)`

I looked into the solution mentioned in the message and then googled a little bit. Unfortunately, the solutions I found were not working, including updating my local `~/.pypirc` file. Like this:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
repository:https://pypi.python.org/pypi   or  repository:https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username:yourusername
password:yourpassword
```

I still got the same error message. What should I do?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Upgrade to the very latest pip and setuptools; install twine:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools twine
```

Edit `~/.pypirc` and comment out or remove `repository`:

```
[pypi]
#repository:https://pypi.python.org/pypi
```

Use twine to upload your module to pypi from within the folder containing the module source, setup.py, and other files:

```
python setup.py sdist
twine upload dist/*
```

See https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem. Plus, I need to run  ```python setup.py sdist ``` to create some dist/* first before ```twine upload dist/*```. I hope this answer will be useful to other people.

Comment: Thanks all, this got me most of the way when I had a similar problem. One extra detail was that you might need to ensure you have Python version to 2.7.9+ otherwise (for me) the `twine upload...` command fails with SSL/TLS errors.

Comment: It's best to not specify repository at all and let twine decide where to upload.

Comment: From official guidelines: " you should edit your ~/.pypirc so that it removes any explicit mention of an URL."

Comment: On Python 2.7.10 (macOS) I get this error: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3.1-py2.7.egg'`

Comment: The text @PiotrDabkowski is referencing is here fyi: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-June/030766.html.

Comment: @collimarco phd (poster), said to install setuptools via pip try `pip install setuptools` then try uploading to twine again

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for legacy solution, try updating your `~/.pypirc` file to this

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username: username
password: password
```

And running

`python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi`

Not sure if it will work right away. Since I did multiple things in order to get it working such as

- Updating both python and python3 (I am still on 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 though)
- Installing `twine` if your system does not have it yet
- Updating `pip`, `setuptools` and `twine` per [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)'s suggestion
- Also `pip3 install -U pip setuptools twine` might help

Comment: What is the new url for the test site the old one was: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi

Comment: Found it here: https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading

Comment: `python setup.py register` and `python setup.py upload` are [deprecated](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi). Do *not* use them.

Comment: Yes, I am using twine now as well. I think I posted this in a transition period

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using twine.

Just install it:

```
pip install twine
```

And simply do:

```
twine upload dist/*
```

> Note: Do this from root of your project