# Python - pypi upload error with twine

Tags: python, http, file-upload, pypi, twine

I have a package for which local installation and distribution work correctly. However, when I try to upload it to pypi with twine, I get the following error message:

> $ twine upload dist/mypackage.tar.gz
>   Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy
>   Uploading mypackage.tar.gz
>   HTTPError: 400 Client Error: author_email: Invalid email address. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy

By the way, I tried also commenting the `author_email` field in setup.py, but the error still remains and I don't think it is related to setup.py.

I tried creating `.pypirc` with no repository specification, as well as without using it at all.

I tried also using setup upload, but  this also failed with a

> $ Upload failed (410) gone: (This API has been deprecated...

As I understand pypi repos are currently in transition phase, but I can't figure out where the problem is.

I'm running twine 1.9.1. and python 3.5.2 (Ubuntu 16.04).

Hope you can help me!

[SOLVED]

It turned out that email address did not match with author name. Changing email address accordingly worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to upload packages to PyPI: 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207128/failed-to-upload-packages-to-pypi-410-gone)

Comment: I think there might be a problem in your setup.py file - can you post that?