# pypi uploading error: twine

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I am trying to upload my Python package for the first time. But, I am getting this error:

> HTTPError: 403 Client Error: You are not allowed to upload to 'test'.
>   for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/

What are the correct steps to upload a Python package?

My ~/.pypirc file contents:

```
[pypi]
username = my_username
password = my_password
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to upload packages to PyPI: 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207128/failed-to-upload-packages-to-pypi-410-gone)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a setup that worked for me

```
[distutils] # this tells distutils what package indexes you can push to
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypi]
repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: MyUsername
password: MyPassword

[pypitest]
repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username: MyUsername
password: MyPassword
```

It may be outdated, though...

Comment: Yeah its outdated. `repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi` is no longer supported.