# Can't upload to PyPi with Twine

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I'm trying to upload a python package to PyPi, using the following commands:

```
pip install -e .
python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

I get this error:

> HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/

I've also tried the following commands:

```
twine upload dist/*
twine upload --repository-url pypi dist/*
twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy dist/*
python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal upload
```

with a .pypirc file located in the same directory I'm running the commands from which is:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypitest]
repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/
username: <username>
password: <password>

[pypi]
repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username: <username>
password: <password>
```

But I'm still asked for my password.
(Also tried this using pypitest, after creating an account on there too, but get the same error)

I've also tried doing the same but with the repository line removed.

The package name I'm trying to upload used to be occupied, but it has been removed now - [https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=&version=1.0.0&:action=display](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=yotI&version=1.0.0&:action=display) says that the package is not found

The username and password I'm using are the same I use to successfully log in to https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=login_form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to upload packages to PyPI: 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207128/failed-to-upload-packages-to-pypi-410-gone)

Comment: Remove `repository` URLs from `~/.pypirc` and try `twine upload` again.

Comment: @phd Thanks but I've tried this, as I said "I've also tried doing the same but with the repository line removed." in my question

Comment: @phd - not a duplicate, as the error returned from Twine is different. In addition, I have tried the solutions suggested already, and they don't solve my issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT**: if you're using **Windows**, check [my other suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791458/1014632)

It looks like some sort of error with the account I was using. The following steps fixed it for me:

1. Create a new account
2. Upload the package with the new account with `twine upload dist/*`
3. Add the previous account (that you originally wanted to upload with) to the package as an owner

Also be aware that the test pypi server `--repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/`, requires a different account to be created from the live server `--repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/`

Comment: Hi! I followed your answer, but when I run `twine upload dist/*`, I get:`HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.`. Can you tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @AnnZen assuming you checked the suggestions on https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth, do you get the same error with you original account?

Answer (score 14):

When we enter the password, the password is not wrong, and I think it's a bug.

I use `-u` for the username and `-p` for the password directly without using the fields provided by the console(the default).

I try to run this in the command:

```sh
twine upload -u YOUR-USERNAME -p YOUR-PASSWORD --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

I run that command on windows:

[image: command-picture]

It works for me. Hope this will help.

Comment: This is *very* dangerous. Anyone who has access to your command line history will be able to see your password.

Comment: Who can access .zsh_history, who can also access .pypirc

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, it seems to be a bug from twine, which I'd need to see its code in order to understand exactly why. For now, your solution really has helped me!

Answer (score 7):

An alternative could have been that copying and pasting wasn't working - when I try to paste the password in the command line it showed this error, but when I typed it out manually it succeeded.

**EDIT**: it looks like this is a known issue with pasting on **Windows**, see suggestion on https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth:

> If you're using Windows and trying to paste your password or token in the Command Prompt or PowerShell, note that Ctrl-V and Shift+Insert won't work. Instead, you can use "Edit > Paste" from the window menu, or enable "Use Ctrl+Shift+C/V as Copy/Paste" in "Properties". This is a [known issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue37426) with Python's getpass module.

Comment: This was the case for me! I had let chrome generate a complex password for me that I couldn't type out, but once I switched to something type-able it works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

PyPi and TestPyPi are separate instances of the package index which have separate user databases.  Therefore, separate accounts must be created.

Maybe you'll get lucky and the test account name won't be taken and you can use the same commands in test as in production.

(Grumble, grumble, zen of python, grumble....)

Comment: [The Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/#using-test-pypi) clarifies that test PyPI uses a *separate* account.

Answer (score 5):

I hit this problem following [the pypi instructions for creating a new package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi). That tutorial takes you through uploading to their test server
(`--repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/`), for which I always get a 403.

For their actual uploads server, (`--repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/`) my credentials work fine. So clearly there's some variation in credentials between their test and live servers, which could be worth considering if you're bumping against this problem.

Comment: [The Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/#using-test-pypi) clarifies that test PyPI uses a *separate* account.

Comment: Thank you kynan. Whether it was missing or I missed it, I don't know, but that fills in part of the puzzle. (I mean, terrible UX! But hey.).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was to (1) **add a new email**, verify it and make it primary.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac or Linux
on terminal
`vim ~/.pypirc`

and add your info:

```
[server-login]
repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: <username>
password: <password>
```

Answer (score 1):

Type in the password manually. Seems dumb but it worked for me.

Comment: How does this answer the question? give more details.

Comment: this solution is intended for the following error....HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information...
if you have already created the package and using twine to upload the package and getting this error, typing in manually the API key as password solves the problem.
if you want to make a package from beginning. try following this guide.
https://medium.com/@faizanzahid09/how-to-create-a-python-package-in-minutes-19f902a61b19

Comment: Ridiculous but this worked for me. I ended up deleting the old token and making new one; this one let me copy/paste it without typing manually.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in my ubuntu 20.04 machine. From this i have figured out something that

- I was using vs code integrated terminal and it was using zsh not bash

Then i use my system terminal and it worked fine for me.

Also make sure you have configured your setup.py properly.

Answer (score 1):

Having **verified accounts** in PyPI and TestPyPI with credentials (`usr1`, `pwd1`) and (`usr2`, `pwd2`) respectively, contents for `~/.pypi`:

```
[distutils]
index-servers=
    pypi
    testpypi

[pypi]
repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username: usr1
password: pwd1

[testpypi]
repository: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
username: usr2
password: pwd2
```

After building the package, publishing for TestPyPI:

```
twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

Publishing for PyPI:

```
twine upload --repository pypi dist/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Please login to [pypi](https://pypi.org) and then visit [account](https://pypi.org/manage/account/) Add a token.

Yes, that's how my problem is solved.

The subsequent steps to create a token：

- Create a .pypirc file in the ~ directory
- Fill in the content provided on the official website as follows:

```
[pypi]
  username = __token__
  password = pypi-******
```

- Then execute the command to upload your package:

```
twine upload dist/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find this is silly but here's a inefficient solution that I used to upload mine.
Type something like this in your editor

```
__token__
yourTokenHere
```

And paste it on username field using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
Also, I find <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> useful to get my clipboard history.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an account under https://test.pypi.org/account/register/.
it looks exactly the same but it use a different database as the pypi.org

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using .pypirc file with a pypi API token. My mistake was that I had written the .pypirc file like:

```
[pypi]
    username = MY_USERNAME
    password = THE_TOKEN_PROVIDED_BY_PYPI
```

However, when an API token is being used, one should use __token__ instead of username. Therefore, changing the .pypirc file to something like the following fixed my issue.

```
[pypi]
    username = __token__
    password = THE_TOKEN_PROVIDED_BY_PYPI
```

Answer (score -1):

I upload a project but when i view on pypi site, it was missing readme.md file. I didn't know how to update so i deleted the project, accept some warnings though.
Lastly, I added readme.md file and tried to upload project again but I got this error. So, i headed to pypi site and completely deleted the last project i uploaded. After then i was able to upload with the same account. Hope this works

Comment: Can you detail the commands you use for your answer ?

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issues.
I was entering my computer username and password.
You need to enter PyPi username and password (:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider providing the command that worked for you. It will be easy to understand.