# Why do I get an error when uploading to pypi?

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I am attempting PyPI's tutorial for the first time, and upon uploading the dist archives, I get this error: 
`HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy`

This was my original command:

`python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`

After reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606692/cant-upload-to-pypi-with-twine), I changed it to

`python -m twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*` but that didn't give any different of a response.

I've followed the tutorial to the letter, and to be honest, I'm not too experienced with working with the file system, so that probably has an impact on it. What am I doing wrong?