# Can't upload package to PyPi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

I've been trying to upload a package to PyPi. I receive this error every time.

```
Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information. 
error: Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information.
```

I googled first and found that there was several issues for this on GitHub. I followed what everybody said was working and no dice.

I made a `~/.pypirc` file with the following contents like everybody said

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
pypi

[pypi]
username: shadeyg56
password:
```

I did fill in the password part but obviously I'm not going to share that.
Then I ran

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

in the correct dir and it returned this

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing shades_package.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to shades_package.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to shades_package.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'shades_package.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'shades_package.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst,
README.txt

running check
creating shades_package-0.1
creating shades_package-0.1\shades_package
creating shades_package-0.1\shades_package.egg-info
copying files to shades_package-0.1...
copying setup.py -> shades_package-0.1
copying shades_package\__init__.py -> shades_package-0.1\shades_package
copying shades_package\test.py -> shades_package-0.1\shades_package
copying shades_package.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> shades_package-0.1\shades_package.eg
g-info
copying shades_package.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> shades_package-0.1\shades_package
.egg-info
copying shades_package.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> shades_package-0.1\shade
s_package.egg-info
copying shades_package.egg-info\not-zip-safe -> shades_package-0.1\shades_packag
e.egg-info
copying shades_package.egg-info\top_level.txt -> shades_package-0.1\shades_packa
ge.egg-info
Writing shades_package-0.1\setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'shades_package-0.1' (and everything under it)
running upload
Password:
Submitting dist\shades_package-0.1.tar.gz to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information.
error: Upload failed (403): Invalid or non-existent authentication information.
```

I can't seem to figure out why its doing this. If anyone knows plz let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: you may want to try [twine](https://github.com/pypa/twine) instead -- there were some recent changes around how uploads work and it's possible the legacy `setup.py upload` no longer works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to upload packages to PyPI: 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207128/failed-to-upload-packages-to-pypi-410-gone)

Answer (score 1):

`python setup.py register` and `python setup.py upload` are [deprecated](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi). Do *not* use them.

Follow the instructions in the [Python Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/):

1. Create an account on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/account/register/) if you haven't yet.
2. Create the source distribution and wheels for your package: `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
3. Install [twine](https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#twine) (or make sure you have version 2.0 or newer): `pip install twine`
4. Check your distribution files for errors: `twine check dist/*`
5. (Optional) [Upload to the PyPI test server](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/#using-test-pypi) first (note: separate user registration required): `twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`
6. Upload to PyPI: `twine upload dist/*`

Answer (score -3):

Maybe double check that the .pypirc files is actually in the same directory as setup.py, since in your question you have called it '~/.pypirc'. The '~/' indicates that the file is in your home directory, which I assume is not where you want it to be.

Comment: [The home directory is actually where `.pypirc` belongs.](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html#pypirc)