# PyPi Test Permanent Redirect

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to register and upload to the pypi test servers (https://pypi.python.org/pypi). I followed the instructions from http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html and everything seems to work up until register:

```
herman@herman-Galago-Pro$ venv/bin/python setup.py register -r pypitest
running register
running egg_info
writing Flask_Meter.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to Flask_Meter.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to Flask_Meter.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'Flask_Meter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'docs'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'docs'
writing manifest file 'Flask_Meter.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
Registering Flask-Meter to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (308): Permanent Redirect
```

Comment: Follow this article https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-testpypi/#using-test-pypi

Comment: The instructions pointed to above are completely outdated. See [the new instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45209514/7976758).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I had to create an account in the pypi test server