# Error 405 trying to upload to pypi

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

Hi I have this code as my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='spongebot',version='1.0',packages=find_packages())
```

But when I try to upload it I can't because of this error:
    Server response (405): Method Not Allowed

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I'm waitin you answer, thanks!!

Comment: can you post your .pyprc file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to upload packages to PyPI: 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207128/failed-to-upload-packages-to-pypi-410-gone)

Comment: Which is the .pyprc file? Sorry if I seem too noob.

Comment: For me this was a simple issue of forgetting to click the verification link in an email from PyPI